# Не получается создать chart в windows forms rider

Tags: c#, winforms, rider

Пытаюсь создать график в винформе, для этого даже пришлось скачать LiveCharts.WinForms, но почему-то когда  его пытаюсь вставить в форму выскакивает ошибка: "Адресат вызова создал исключение". Не нашла нигде информации об этом, может в rider проблема какая-то, может не для того фреймворка. Подскажите или если пользовались графиками в winforms посоветуйте какую-нибудь библиотеку дл этого.

Comment: `Адресат вызова создал исключение` - это заголовок о том, что произошла ошибка, а не сама ошибка. Копайте глубже и смотрите на что именно ругается, от этого и отталкивайтесь.